# pandas: changing values according to conditions within group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to figure how to adjust some values within the same group with pandas.

In the df below i have two groups(111, 222); within the groups, the 'freq' are ranked. however, i'd like to adjust the 'rank' that have the same 'freq' within the group to have the same 'rank' (ascending order).

Example: group:111, freq 1 are the same and they are ranked 5 and 6; however, i'd would like to adjust them to the same rank (showed in the adj_rank column)

```
+-----+------+------+----------+
| id  | freq | rank | adj_rank |
+-----+------+------+----------+
| 111 |    1 |    5 |        5 |
| 111 |    1 |    6 |        5 |
| 111 |    2 |    1 |        1 |
| 111 |    3 |    2 |        2 |
| 111 |    4 |    3 |        3 |
| 111 |    5 |    4 |        4 |
| 222 |    1 |    2 |        2 |
| 222 |    2 |    1 |        1 |
| 222 |    3 |    4 |        4 |
| 222 |    3 |    5 |        4 |
| 222 |    4 |    3 |        3 |
| 222 |    5 |    6 |        6 |
+-----+------+------+----------+
```

code for df

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'id':[111,111,111,111,111,111,
             222,222,222,222,222,222],
'freq':[1,1,2,3,4,5,
        1,2,3,3,4,5],
'rank':[5,6,1,2,3,4,
        2,1,4,5,3,6],
'adj_rank':[5,5,1,2,3,4,
        2,1,4,4,3,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

thank you @Anurag Dabas for the sugguestion, however, when i expanded the df, the result will be off when using the solution you provided. If you  look at the below df, when using the code you provided, adj_rank (1st row) shows 11, however, the correct value should be 4.  Kindly advise, thanks.
expanded df:

```
╔═════╦══════╦══════╦══════════╗
║ id  ║ freq ║ rank ║ adj_rank ║
╠═════╬══════╬══════╬══════════╣
║ 333 ║    1 ║   11 ║       11 ║
║ 333 ║    2 ║    1 ║        1 ║
║ 333 ║    2 ║    2 ║        1 ║
║ 333 ║    1 ║    5 ║        4 ║
║ 333 ║    1 ║    6 ║        4 ║
║ 333 ║    1 ║    7 ║        4 ║
║ 333 ║    1 ║    8 ║        4 ║
║ 333 ║    1 ║    9 ║        4 ║
║ 333 ║    3 ║    3 ║        3 ║
║ 333 ║    3 ║    4 ║        3 ║
║ 333 ║    1 ║   10 ║        4 ║
╚═════╩══════╩══════╩══════════╝
```

expanded df codes:

```
data = {'id':[333,333,333,333,333,333,
             333,333,333,333,333],
'freq':[1,2,2,1,1,1,        
        1,1,3,3,1],        
'rank':[11,1,2,5,6,7,8,        
        9,3,4,10,]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Many thanks Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try substracting the cumalative count of `['id','freq']` to the original rank:

```
df['adj_rank']=df['rank']-df.groupby(['id','freq']).cumcount()
#df['adj_rank']=df['rank'].sub(df.groupby(['id','freq']).cumcount())
```

output of `df`:

```
    id  freq    rank    adj_rank
0   111     1   5       5
1   111     1   6       5
2   111     2   1       1
3   111     3   2       2
4   111     4   3       3
5   111     5   4       4
6   222     1   2       2
7   222     2   1       1
8   222     3   4       4
9   222     3   5       4
10  222     4   3       3
11  222     5   6       6
```

**Update:**

After substacting the `cumcount()` sort the values of the dataframe by using `sort_values()` then groupby `['id','freq']` then transform the first value of rank and finally sort the `index` of df so that it comes in initial position:

```
df['rank']=df['rank']-df.groupby(['id','freq']).cumcount()
df=df.sort_values(['id','freq','rank'])
df['rank']=df.groupby(['id','freq'],sort=False)['rank'].transform('first')
df=df.sort_index()
```

Comment: thanks for the input, however, something seems off when i expanded the df. I've updated the question. kindly advise. thanks

Comment: @ManOnTheMoon that depends on how you calculated the rank initially

Comment: @ Anurag Dabas the ranking is derived using probability of freq occurrence.  the probability is calculate in sequential. example freq 1's probability of occurrence are  0.1, 0.11, 0.12, 0.13 , 0.14 , 0.15 , 0.16 within id 333, hence, when using 'dense' for ranking,  freq 1 provides a sequential ranking(5 to 11). however, as mentioned, i need the same freq within the group to be adjusted to the same rank.

Comment: ps, changing to global mean for probability  calculation is not applicable as i need the means to be sequentially calculated.

Comment: thanks. it solved the problem. however, there's seems to be some kind of kink in jupyter. when i tried it with a full data set, some values are off. Will try to find a solution. thanks again

Comment: @ManOnTheMoon maybe restart your kernel and try again....btw if you got your solution(or try to solve jupyter problem first then check again if the solution is working or not) then try considering accepting the answer to indicate others that the issue is solved....Thanks **:)**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236134/discussion-between-manonthemoon-and-anurag-dabas).